# Setting default route in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am creating a project in C# MVC and was using actions. Due to the requirements, now I am using Route to hide the controller name and display just the page name.

route config

```
 routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Law",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Law", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

controller 1 (to access this : http://localhost:17920/dashboard) and (http://localhost:17920/alert)

```
    public class LawController : Controller
    {
        [Route("dashboard")]
        [ActionName("Home")]
        public ActionResult Home()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        [Route("alert")]
        [ActionName("alert-list")]
        public ActionResult AlertList()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

controller 2 (to access this : http://localhost:17920/list)

```
    public class ListController : Controller
    {
        [Route("list")]
        [ActionName("list-of-return")]
        public ActionResult listOfReturn()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

What I am trying is when I enter this http://localhost:17920 as a default URL, then http://localhost:17920/dashboard should be displayed by default.
Thanks.

Comment: do you have other routes in the routes object ?

Comment: Yes, i do have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `RoutePrefix` over the `Controller` like below. Also update your `Route("dashboard")` to `Route("Home")` because that is your default action name on route configuration.

```
[RoutePrefix("Law")]
public class LawController : Controller
{
    [Route("Home")]
    [ActionName("Home")]
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    // Other action methods
}
```

Please also refer https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/ for more details.

---

**Edit** As per edit in your question it is more clear what you want. From your existing code you just need to add one more `Route` over `LawController`'s `Home` action as below, so it could match `http://localhost:17920/` & `http://localhost:17920/dashboard` to that `action` method.

```
public class LawController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    [Route("dashboard")]
    [ActionName("Home")]
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    [Route("alert")]
    [ActionName("alert-list")]
    public ActionResult AlertList()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: http://localhost:17920/list and http://localhost:17920 both returns an error page (resources cannot be found.)

Comment: Yes it worked. [Route("")] works. Thanks Karan